# Resources used for translations suddenly not gets translated

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I use resources to translate my ASP.NET Web Forms application. I use the plugin resx-Manager. This works fine to translate to four languages. But suddenly, it refuse to translate new strings added to the resource file, even when they have a translation. Only new string always use English no matter  which culture is used. This is really confusing. The old strings works perfect.

- Rebooted IIS
- Rebuilt the project
- Compared generated code but it looks identical to other strings.

When getting translation for string "X" it returns "X-sv". But when adding string Y it returns "Y-en" but I expect "Y-sv."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have accidently added a language specific x.resources.dll in the bin folder. Instead they are stored in separated folder with the culture name. The file in the bin-folder was a few days old which explains why I didn't get the new strings.